# installing Ubuntu from Live USB

Tags: system-installation, uefi

**env:  Ubuntu 18.04, mini-ITX custom build on ASUS X470 Motherboard, M2 Samsung 970 SSD.  No Windows, this system is Linux only**

This is a bit embarrassing.  As far as I can tell, when we tried the live USB (written with Rufus) and chose to install it installed, not on the SSD, but on the USB.  When my son boots up the machine it asks for his password, this is not just the Try Ubuntu option.

But, take out the USB and the system has nothing to load from, it doesn't see anything on the SSD and stays in black screen.

I tried `boot-repair` and it asked me to run some commands, which I did, but then ended with **Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1p1/efi/.../grub*.efi file!**.  That is the Samsung SSD.

Now, on the ASUS UEFI menu, Boot option, I can choose the Samsung SSD, <s>but not that .efi file in it.  So, that didn't solve anything.</s>

Update:  I did manage to find the Ubuntu boot in the ASUS uefi boot menu, but choosing it still doesn't bring up a boot screen.  To an extent, that doesn't surprise me as this system was not installed as such:  we didn't pick a username and password, languages, etc... that was only done on the USB.

This was the `boot-repair` diagnostics:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CMBPvCYBzW/

and this was the actual repair log, when I chose to ask `boot-repair` to do the suggested repair:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8XTfQHzvcY/.

Now, it seems to me that the easiest thing to do would be to use the Live USB to install itself again, but this time to the SSD, not to the USB itself.  Is there a command to do that?

This is a brand new machine and I really don't care about the contents of the USB or the SSD at this point, just want to get the proper SSD-based boot working.

Comment: Format the SSD and try again first.

Comment: Your SSD is the newer NVMe type. And it shows a LVM UEFI type install. Did you also choose full drive encryption which requires LVM, otherwise LVM is not really for beginners as you cannot use gparted but must use LVM tools. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Answer (score 0):

I can see how that can happen, in the installer menu all the drives kind-of look the same. What you want to do is re-flash the USB stick with the ISO you want to install on to your computer. Using a boot repair on you USB stick will try to fix the OS you installed on to it by mistake. The easiest thing to do is re-flash the ISO to the USB drive and then install it to the SSD. I've been doing this sort of think for a while and I can see myself making the same mistake.

When you go to setup the drive partitions don't use the installer use GParted, it come with the Ubuntu Live ISO. The partition table you set up in GParted will be seen by the installer when you got to install the operating system. GParted is a really easy program to use and it's a lot more straight forward than the installer for drive partitioning. Since you said that you were having a problem telling the drives form one another, in GParted go to the file menu: View/Device Information, this will show you the model of the drive. Usually SSDs have SSD in the Model name and USBs have USB in the model name, so make sure that you see it says SSD. Also, make sure the size of the drive you have selected is close to the SSD's size. Drive sizes are usually rounded up, so the numbers you see in GParted will be a bit smaller than what the dive size is sold as. For example, a 3TB drive is really a 2.73TB drive when you look at in in GParted. To switch between drives in GParted use the drop-down menu at the right had conner of the window under the menu bar.

- Once you find the SSD in GParted:

  - Create a partition table bay selecting the drive in the list next to Device Information. In file menu: Device/Create Partition Table, and create a gpt table.
  - Now create a EXT4 file-system. With the volume selected, go to file menu: Partition/Format To/Ext4.
  - To make these changes take effect click the green check mark underneath the partition menu bar option. Wait for you changes to be applied and then open the installer and follow it's prompts.
- Back in the installer when you get to drive configuration. Select something else.

  - Make sure you SSD is selected and the installer should see your formatted drive. Select the area for the installer and assign it to be your root partition. This should also be your destination for GRUB. GRUB wants the /dev/sda, it doesn't need the specific partition (/dev/sda1).
  - Then continue trough the installer's prompts.